# unable to get a message to display

Tags: javascript

I have to create a code which asks the user to input two numbers.  The program needs to multiply the two numbers and then display the answer in a displayed message.  ie: 5 x 7 is 35! (assuming the numbers the user inputed were 5 and 7.)

Here is the code I have now.

```
<title></title> 

<script type="text/javascript">
 var num1 = 0;
 var num2 = 0;
 var calculatedNum = 0;

 function calculation() {
 //create a integer variable called num2
 //Purpose: second variable
 var num2 = 0; // integer second variable

//create a integer variable called calculatedNum
 //Purpose: num1 x num2
 var calculatedNum = 0; // integer num1 x num2

//ask user '"Please type the first number"'
 //and put the answer in num1
 num1 = prompt("Please type the first number");

//ask user '"Please type the second number."'
 //and put the answer in num2
 num2 = prompt("Please type the second number.");

//Tell user: num1 + "x" + num2 + "=" + calculatedNum
 alert (num1 + "x" + num2 + "=" + calculatedNum);

} // end calculation function

}end program


</script>
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I assume `}end program` is a mistake?

Comment: where have you calculated the multiplication ?

Comment: redone the code. but still can't get it to work.  everything in original code above what is pasted stayed the same.

  //ask user '"Please type the second number."'
  //and put the answer in num2
  num2 = prompt("Please type the second number."); 

  //set calculatedNum = num1 * num2

  //Tell user: num1 + "x" + num2 + "is" + calculatedNum + "!"
  alert (num1 + "x" + num2 + "is" + calculatedNum + "!");

  } // end calculation function

  


</script>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>JavaScript Functions for Jalyn Jellison</h1>
  
</body>
</html>

Comment: `calculatedNum=num1*num2`, maybe?

Comment: @JalynJellison, try my answer. Check out the demo. It works.  Just copy the first block of code and put it between `<script>` and `</script>`.

Comment: Just so it's said, `prompt` rather sucks in web pages, for various reasons. In most cases, you'd do better to have input elements in a page and a content element of some kind to place the output in.  Something like http://jsfiddle.net/2WQQd/

Comment: @cHao, so does `alert`.  But as the OP is struggling with the basics of how to declare and call a function, not sure it's worth getting into these other topics.

Answer (score 1):

You've overcomplicated things for yourself.  Just do this:

```
<script>
    var num1 = prompt('Please type the first number'),
        num2 = prompt('Please type the second number');
    alert(num1 + "x" + num2 + "=" + num1 * num2);
</script>
```

[Demo 1](http://jsfiddle.net/rvXcw/)

Or, if you want to wrap this in a function so you can call it from somewhere else:

```
<script>
    function calculation() {
        var num1 = prompt('Please type the first number'),
            num2 = prompt('Please type the second number');
        alert(num1 + "x" + num2 + "=" + num1 * num2);
    };
    calculation();
</script>
```

[Demo 2](http://jsfiddle.net/rvXcw/1/)

Comment: used wrap, but still no message

Comment: @JalynJellison, I've made this super easy for you: I've edited my answer so that you can see the two options within script tags.  Just copy either block and completely replace your script block. This will work and is a clean solution.

Answer (score 1):

Try it

```
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
var calculatedNum = 0;

function calculation() {
    num1 = prompt("Please type the first number");
    num2 = prompt("Please type the second number.");
    calculatedNum = (num1*num2);
    alert(num1 + "x" + num2 + "=" + calculatedNum);
}
```

use `calculation();` to call :)

Comment: this is the code I used, but still no messages displayed

<head>
<title>JavaScript Functions</title>

<script type="text/javascript">
var num1 = 0;
var num2 = 0;
var calculatedNum = 0;

function calculation() {
    num1 = prompt("Please type the first number");
    num2 = prompt("Please type the second number.");
    calculatedNum = (num1*num2);
    alert(num1 + "x" + num2 + "=" + calculatedNum);
}

 
</script>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>JavaScript Functions for Jalyn Jellison</h1>
  
</body>
</html>

Answer (score 0):

```
<title></title> 

<script type="text/javascript">
 var num1 = 0;
 var num2 = 0;
 var calculatedNum = 0;

 function calculation() {
 //create a integer variable called num2
 //Purpose: second variable
 var num2 = 0; // integer second variable

//create a integer variable called calculatedNum
 //Purpose: num1 x num2
 var calculatedNum = 0; // integer num1 x num2

//ask user '"Please type the first number"'
 //and put the answer in num1
 num1 = prompt("Please type the first number");

//ask user '"Please type the second number."'
 //and put the answer in num2
 num2 = prompt("Please type the second number.");
calculatedNum = num1*num2;
//Tell user: num1 + "x" + num2 + "=" + calculatedNum
 alert (num1 + "x" + num2 + "=" + calculatedNum);

} // end calculation function


calculation();
</script>
```

This works as intended. 
you were having an extra "}end program" at the end.

Comment: I tried using this but can't get the messages to display

Comment: you have to call the function also to get the desired results.
Try now just added `calculation();`at the end.

Comment: that worked! but now only no matter what two numbers i enter when prompted it comes back with zero in the answer

Comment: you have done `var calculatedNum = 0;`
but never chnaged its value; 


`calculatedNum = num1*num2;`
this line must be missing from the code u executed. Actually its missing in the original code in question. Please make sure its there.

Comment: Thanks for all the help.  I finally got it to work correctly.  I had calculatedNum = num1*num2; commented out.

Comment: your welcome and now you can remove the downvote!!